# NPM Instalar dependencias automaticamente

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Estoy generando una librería y tiene paquetes de terceros que son necesarios para que funcione.

¿Existe alguna manera de que en el momento de ejecutar el npm install mi-libreria, instale las dependencias que necesita para funcionar?

Entiendo que habría que configurar algo en el package.json, pero no encuentro el que.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el contenido de `package.json` e indicar qué dependencias son las que no se instalan? Es posible que las agregaras sólo a `devDependencies` con `--save-dev`.

Comment: No, la dependencia se instala correctamente, la cosa es que esa dependencia tiene dependencias necesarias para funcionar. ng-packagr las mete en peerDependencies, y no se instalan de forma automática.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el contenido de `package.json` y la versión de `npm` que usas? Sin ver el contenido nos resultará más difícil averiguar qué te está pasando.

Answer (score 1):

Asegúrate que cuando instales las dependencias que necesitas lo hagas de la siguiente manera:

```
npm install [nombre-dependencia] --save
```

Esto hará que se añada al package.json y cada vez que ejecutes *"npm install"* se instalarán las que tengas ahí. Por otra parte si quieres instalar dependencias que no quieres que vayan a *"producción"* por decirlo de alguna manera deberás hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
npm install [nombre-dependencia] --save-dev
```

Comment: Si, esos son los comandos básicos de uso, hasta ahí lo tengo claro, pero el escenario es diferente, mi duda surge cuando instalo mi propia libreria, que tengo que configurar para que haciendo solo el npm install, me instale la libreria y todas las dependencia que esta tiene.